p VaR: what is p?
English Wikipedia describes $p$ as the probability of a loss exceeding $p$ VaR. But I've also seen $(1-p)$ VaR to denote the same thing (for example German Wikipedia seems to go that way). So, eg, $95\%$ VaR instead of $5\%$ VaR. Is there an über-convention or reference for this?

I think 95% Var so (1-p) Var is more common and convention. Think laziness forced the p Var convention (or its just assumed one knows from the context)

In most, if not all, documentation and practitioner talks I have perceived the convention of a $(1-p)VaR$, e.g. 99%, 99.9% etc. This way, we are "(1-p) confident", that the loss will not exceed VaR.
